# Set colorcolumn to textwidth only when textwidth is set

Tags: colorcolumn

I want `colocolumn` to be 80 by default for all buffers, but if `textwidth` is set (and not 0) for a buffer, then I want `colorcolumn` to be `+0`.

I know this could be done by just setting `tw` to 80 in my `.vimrc` but I do not want a max line length because the auto line breaks can easily lead to syntax errors.

I have tried using an autocmd to set the colorcolumn option whenever the `tw` changes but the problem with this is that the `OptionSet` event does not fire when vim starts up, so any `tw` settings by some file-type plugin would not change the `colorcolumn` setting.

```
autocmd! OptionSet textwidth call s:SetColorColumn()
function! s:SetColorColumn()
    if &textwidth == 0
        setlocal colorcolumn=80
    else
        setlocal colorcolumn=+0
    endif
endfunction
```

When using the `FileType` event, the problem is similar. Although it fires on startup it fires when the `filetype` is set but before the `ftplugin` files were sourced so the `tw` was not yet set.

Is there any way I can accomplish this or will I just have to set `textwidth` or just live with `colorcolumn` being 80 all the time?

---

I'm using vim 8.0.0086 from the terminal.

And here is the output of `vim --version` (just in case):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 15 2016 18:04:06)
Included patches: 1-86
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     +tcl/dyn
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl/dyn        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl    -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc   -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to add the same function to the `BufEnter` autocmd:

```
set textwidth=0

function! s:SetColorColumn()
    if &textwidth == 0
        setlocal colorcolumn=80
    else
        setlocal colorcolumn=+0
    endif
endfunction

augroup colorcolumn
    autocmd!
    autocmd OptionSet textwidth call s:SetColorColumn()
    autocmd BufEnter * call s:SetColorColumn()
augroup end
```

From [`:help BufEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufEnter):

```
BufEnter                        After entering a buffer.  Useful for setting
                                options for a file type.  Also executed when
                                starting to edit a buffer, after the
                                BufReadPost autocommands.
```

Comment: Must have totally skipped over that event when reading the docs, works like a charm.
Minor issue: the `OptionSet` event does not seem to fire when I set the file type myself while editing and the plugin changes the `textwidth`, do you know of any event that could handle such a case?
I'm going to accept this answer though, because that's not something that's going to happen very often.

Comment: @patrick96 I think you're looking for the `FileType` event? `autocmd FileType * call s:SetColorColumn()`.

Comment: unfortunately not. `FileType` fires when setting the file type but before the file type plugins are sourced

Comment: @patrick96 It's probably best to update the question with the commands your using and contents of the file you're sourcing, so I (or someone else) can reproduce the problem and fix it.

Comment: It's alright. Changing the filetype while editing is something that rarely ever happens and if it does you can just either reload the file or set `tw` manually